# Issue after updating android-maps-extensions to a newer version

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, android-maps-extensions

I had been using an older version of the said library in a project of mine. However, today when I updated to the latest version, I realized that its package names etc had changed (major version switch from 1.x.x to 2.x.x).

From **pl.mg6.android.maps.extensions.SupportMapFragment** it was now **com.androidmapsextensions.SupportMapFragment**.

I made the necessary import changes. However, the following line in my code that worked fine before is now showing an error:

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getExtendedMap();
```

map is of type GoogleMap (com.androidmapsextensions.GoogleMap).

Here is the map in my XML

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    class="com.androidmapsextensions.SupportMapFragment" />
```

As you can see I've changed the XML from pl6.... to the new package name too.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the error say exactly?

Comment: @MaciejGórski "SupportMapFragment cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: I also just updated my google play services library

Comment: Is the import statement in this file correct? Are you using Android Studio?

Comment: Actually, I missed an import and Eclipse didn't suggest anything. I was importing gms SupportMapFragment class instead of the mapsextension SupportMapFragment class.